# Vue: how to make component providing info about logged in user reactive to session data?

Tags: session, vue.js

I understand how to use a Vue plugin like vue-session for creating and holding a session.
But I am not sure how to deal with user data from a session, especially when it comes to reactivity.
E.g.:
I have a User component in the navigation header which displays the currently logged in user. How do I ensure that the username shown via this User component is reactive? In other words: if somewhen while using the application a login happens (to enable restricted functions), then how can the User component know?

Is `$watch` the right way to go? But this means polling, doesn't it?

How can I ensure that the user data stored in the session plugin is reactive?

Imagine such a component which visualises the logged in user:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="user.username">
        Logged in as {{user.username}}
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        Not logged in.
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "LoggedInUser",
  data() {
    return {
      user: {
        username: null,
        email: null
      }
    };
  },
  computed: {
    user() {
      return { this.$session.user };
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I do not want to determine the session user in the `create` method because it should be reactive (reactive to logout/login).

What's the best option for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use a computed property (like you did) that uses a getter from a Vuex store (or a mapped getter in Vuex speak). All the state stored in a Vuex store is reactive so you'll get what you're looking for.

Instead of storing the current user in the `$session` from vue-session, it would be stored in the Vuex store.

Vuex: https://vuex.vuejs.org/

## About vue-session

I had a quick look at that plugin and its [source](https://github.com/victorsferreira/vue-session/blob/master/index.js) (only ~100 lines) and there is definitely no reactivity option in there. It's essentially a convenience interface over `window.localStorage`. `$watch` only works on reactive data (e.g. a component's `data` object) which is not provided by this plugin.

Reactivity could be retrofitted in there with [Vue.observable(object)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable) I guess though.

A nice read on reactivity: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54492326/1030527

Comment: That's good to know. However, how would it be possible without Vuex?

Comment: @andimeier see my edit. By the way, is this "see my edit" message useful? i.e. do you get a notification anyway when I edit my answer?

Comment: sorry, was not at all intentionally - I was sure I answered you on Jun 25, but now I saw that apparently the POST submit did not make its way to StackOverflow. Yes, it is definitely useful, I appreciate this comment very much because it points me at re-reading your post in case I do not notice. That't how it should be - I find this makes very much sense. - And BTW, thank you very much for your answers, they have been very helpful to me! I just did not close the issue yet because I would like to know how it works without having to resort to Vuex ...

Comment: BTW, in the meantime I decided to go with Vuex - which works very well for this use case. However, I was interested what would be the easiest way to solve such an issue with Vue, I still have to peek into Vue.observable() ...

Comment: I accepted the answer because  it points out two useful things: (1) you can use `Vue.observable(object)` to make something reactive and (2) especially for my problem the Vuex store is a good and proven solution.