# Which thread runs Vue watcher in web?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webapi, watch

I want to use watch with async await for axios call.

Official Vue document also recommend to use it when it's needed.
(https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html)

But someone said when you use Watcher with async await, it will take javascript's single thread, so all the other code has to stop - including UI.
So watcher should ONLY be used asyncrounously.

Is this true? As far as I know, Javascript in web offers background web api such as Dom, Ajax.., so I thought other codes could run asyncronously?

I just don't know if Javascript's main thread runs Vue Watcher so other codes has to wait
or background web api (maybe Ajax since my code below uses axios call in the below example?) runs it so other main thread could run other codes asyncrounously.

Please help if anyone knows.

```
export defualt{
  watch: {
    apple: async function (n) {
      await axios.fetchSomethings(query);
    },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      apple: "redApple"
    }
  },

  methods: {
    changeApple(){
      this.apple = "blueApple";
    }
  }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with threading. A watcher just fires your callback when the watched value changes. That uses the same reactive system as the rest of Vue, which is based on proxy objects, not on anything running in a separate thread constantly monitoring something.

Comment: @deceze What does it mean? She are asking if there is a problem with thread performance. please reply to me clear answer.

Comment: There wont be any issues with async await in the watcher.

Comment: If you want to get deep into it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54476619/476

Comment: Thank you. I got that what you guys mean. But then what does main thread and js background web api do in Vue system? @deceze

Comment: What does that mean? What do you think these terms mean?

Comment: Your current understanding is wrong. As suggested above, asynchronous != threading. And also asynchronous != async/await. Unless you use *blocking* code in a watcher (e.g. synchronous for loop that takes a considerable time), not using async/await doesn't block anything. This isn't related to Vue as it doesn't do anything specific with threads that wouldn't be in vanilla JS. There are workers in JS for multithreading but they aren't relevant here.